# How to restore TDE encrypted DB on AWS (with certificate not stored in master)?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, transparent-data-encryption

The way Amazon RDS enable TDE feature is to generate a certificate stored in master. However, I need to restore a database that is encrypted by another certificate.

I have the cert file, private key file and password.
But I can only create a certificate with files and password in **ANY OTHER DATABASE EXCEPT MASTER**.

Could you please give me some advice on how to restore TDE encrypted DB with certificate **not stored in master**? Or is there a method to to back up certificate at master in Amazon RDS?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a gap with RDS.  Apparently the advice is to remove TDE on the source DB then back it up so that it can be restored to RDS.

This is a pretty poor scenario in my opinion - switching on and off TDE should not be taken lightly.  I really hope that AWS enable some functionality to backup/restore certificates for TDE